# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package from __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Suppose I have a structure like this

```
server
├─────────app
           ├─────main
                   ├─────models
                   |           ├───── admin.py 
                   |
                   ├───── __init__.py (contains db function)
```

In this structure, I tried to import "db" inside admin.py like this
"from .. import db"

but getting import error:
**ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package**

This server is a flask app module and **init**.py contains my create_app(config) function.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/layout/), you **init**.py should be at the same level than your folder `main`.

However you can try to import from the module name directly like :

```py
from app.main.models import db
```